# How to adjust Pillow EPS to JPG quality

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert EPS images to JPEG using Pillow. But the results are of low quality. I'm trying to use `resize` method, but it gets completely ignored. I set up the size of JPEG image as `(3600, 4700)`, but the resulted image has `(360, 470)` size. My code is:

```
eps_image = Image.open('img.eps')
height = eps_image.height * 10
width = eps_image.width * 10
new_size = (height, width)
print(new_size)  # prints (3600, 4700)
eps_image.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
eps_image.save(
    'img.jpeg',
    format='JPEG'
    dpi=(9000, 9000),
    quality=95)
```

**UPD.** Vasu Deo.S noticed one my error, and thanks to him the JPG image has become bigger, but quality is still low. I've tried different DPI, sizes, resample values for `resize` function, but the result does not change much. How can i make it better?

[image]

Comment: can you add the original image in the question too. As it would help resolving the error a lot easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that PIL is a **raster** image processor, as opposed to a **vector** image processor. It *"rasterises"* vector images (such as your EPS file and SVG files) onto a grid when it opens them because it can only deal with rasters.

If that grid doesn't have enough resolution, you can never regain it. Normally, it rasterises at 100dpi, so if you want to make bigger images, you need to rasterise onto a larger grid before you even get started.

Compare:

```
from PIL import Image

eps_image = Image.open('image.eps')
eps_image.save('a.jpg')
```

The result is 540x720:

[image]

And this:

```
from PIL import Image

eps_image = Image.open('image.eps')
# Rasterise onto 4x higher resolution grid
eps_image.load(scale=4)   
eps_image.save('a.jpg')
```

The result is 2160x2880:

[image]

You now have enough quality to resize however you like.

Note that you don't need to write any Python to do this at all - **ImageMagick** will do it all for you. It is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows and you just use it in Terminal. The equivalent command is like this:

```
magick -density 400 input.eps -resize 800x600 -quality 95  output.jpg
```

Comment: `@Mark` In ImageMagick 7, use magick only, not magick convert or you will get ImageMagick 6 behavior. The other tools such as identify and mogrify and montage would need to be prefaced by magick

Comment: @MarkSetchell When i try to run your PIL code, I get `TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scale'`? Is this load function of PIL or some other image processing module?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S It's standard Pillow... https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#eps

Comment: @MarkSetchell So scale argument is only legal if the give image file is of the extension .eps?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Yes, as is the case here.

Comment: THANK YOU for the load function with the scale parameter!  That solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

It's because `eps_image.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)` returns an resized copy of an image. Therefore you have to store it in a separate variable. Just change:-

```
eps_image.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

to

```
eps_image = eps_image.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

**UPDATE:-**

These may not solve the problem completely, but still would help.

- You are trying to save your output image as a `.jpeg`, which is a
  lossy compression format, therefore information is lost during the
  compression/transformation (for the most part). Change the output
  file extension to a lossless compression format like `.png` so that
  data would not be compromised during compression. Also change
  `quality=95` to `quality=100` in `Image.save()`
- You are using `Image.ANTIALIAS` for resampling the image, which is
  not that good when upscaling the image (it has been replaced by
  `Image.LANCZOS` in newer version, the clause still exists for
  backward compatibility). Try using `Image.BICUBIC`, which produces
  quite favorable results (for the most part) when upscaling the image.

Comment: Thank you, it was really an issue with my code. But even fixing this does not solve the problem with quality. I've updated my question with more details. Can you provide some more advice?