# Pillow & EPS file is bad - what do use to open EPS files perfectly?

Tags: python, image-processing, vector, python-imaging-library

I have a EPS file like this:
https://gofile.io/d/Kv2cwo

When doing conversion to png via Pillow, I get this result:

```
from PIL import Image
eps_image = Image.open("raw.eps")
eps_image.load(scale=10)
eps_image.save("png.png")
```

[image]

it is absolutely rasterised - because PIL is doing rasterisation.
When converting in Adobe Illustrator, I get this:
[image]

So how can I achieve this in python?

With best regards,
Martin

Comment: The image (from Illustrator) you have uploaded to this post is also rasterised. What exactly do you expect to get as a result? What do you want to do with the EPS file? Convert to a PNG file?

Comment: Have you experimented with larger or smaller `scale` values?

Comment: No this is not true, like you see the second image I have linked, this is exported from illustrator and without pixelation.

Comment: When I open it in my browser it says it has 1024 times 1024 pixels. As it is a PNG file, it *must* be rasterised. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics: "PNG is a raster-graphics file format."

Comment: Yes, but the image I have posted in high quality is also png, but exported from illustrator, and I want to achieve this in python … do you understand now?

Comment: So you are asking how to rasterise an EPS image using Pillow with a higher resolution than what the code you have shown does.

Comment: Yes but I think pillow can’t do it in high quality because it’s not a Vector Processing Engine - if you know how to do it it would be nice, but I think it’s not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust Pillow EPS to JPG quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543825/how-to-adjust-pillow-eps-to-jpg-quality)

Comment: No, I found this already. All you can find via google search is not helping - I think we need to find an other lib to convert- or it’s closed to illustrator/Adobe to be able to do this. Because no other software can open it at high quality as well.

Comment: Well. Have you *tried* to use a higher value for `scale`? What happens if you use `scale=100` or `scale=1000`?

Comment: this does not change anything to the quality.

Comment: The idea that Illustrator does this better because it is a vector drawing program is incorrect. Any software that is able to read an EPS file will read and rasterize it the same way as Illustrator. However, it is possible that PIL doesn’t know how to read EPS files, and all it can do for you is extract the preview. Try converting the file with ImageMagick.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, but I do not find any convert command setup at google which can do this. Can you show me how you would do it with ImageMagick and if this can even do it? Thanks!

Comment: On Linux the command is `convert foo.eps foo.png`. Look through the ImageMagick docs to learn how to set the output image size, to get the resolution you want.

Comment: No this is not working. It produces an absolute pixelated output.

Comment: Try `convert -density 288 input.eps output.png`

Comment: By default, ImageMagick rasterises at 72dpi, which is pretty low, so if you use 288dpi you will get 4x the quality. It will take longer and be bigger too, but that's what you want.

Comment: @MarkSetchell like you can see here: https://gofile.io/d/8mAA9P this is absolutely not working.